# actionSupport not rendering siblings

Tags: apex, visualforce

Here is my code the idea is when the user picks a value from the drop down i want to render siblings. I looked at http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Visualforce_DynamicEditPage  but i can't get mine to render the conditional part at the bootom (the 2nd close date)

Any ideas how to accomplish this? I don't want to nest them in a pageblockSection

```
        <apex:page standardController="Opportunity" sidebar="false">
        <apex:sectionHeader title="Edit Opportunity" subtitle="{!opportunity.name}"/>
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Opportunity" id="thePageBlock" mode="edit">
                <apex:pageMessages />
                <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>                
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                <apex:actionRegion >
                    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Basic Information" columns="1">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.name}"/>
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                            <apex:outputLabel value="Stage"/>
                            <apex:outputPanel >
                                <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.stageName}">
                                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="test"
                                                        status="status" />
                                </apex:inputField>
                                <apex:actionStatus startText="applying value..." id="status"/>
                            </apex:outputPanel>
                        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.amount}"/>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.closedate}"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:actionRegion>
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Closed Lost Information" columns="1"
                                       rendered="{!opportunity.stageName == 'Closed Lost'}" id="test">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.CloseDate}"  required="true"/>

                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: You should add an ID to the pageMessages tag and rerender that as well. I suspect that you aren't seeing an error which is occurring on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outputPanel with id=test does not render if at load the Stage is not Closed Lost.
I don't believe it is possible to rerender an element (pageBlockSection in this case) which hasn't rendered when the page loaded. You would need to reRender a parent such as the pageBlock.

Here is a great [blog post](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/visualforce-re-rendering-woes.html) explaining this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

change your actionsupport as below as your action region encompasses other required fields which i believe are not getting validated:

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="test, thePageBlock"
                                                        status="status" />
```

but it is better if you move the actionregion to include only the stage field (source) as below:

```
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Basic Information" columns="1">
                        <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.name}"/>
                        <apex:PageBlockSectionItem >
                         <apex:outputLabel value="Stage"/>
                         <apex:actionRegion >
                          <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}">
                          <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="test" />
                          </apex:inputField>
                         </apex:actionRegion>
                      </apex:PageBlockSectionItem>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.amount}"/>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.closedate}"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>

                <apex:outputPanel id="test">
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Closed Lost Information" columns="1"
                                       rendered="{!opportunity.stageName == 'Closed Lost'}">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.CloseDate}"  required="true"/>

                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                </apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code for you.

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" sidebar="false">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Edit Opportunity" subtitle="{!Opportunity.Name}"/>
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="Edit Opportunity" id="thePageBlock" mode="edit">
<apex:pageMessages />
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
  <apex:actionRegion >
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="Basic Information" columns="1">
      <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Name}"/>
      <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
         <apex:outputLabel value="Stage"/>
         <apex:outputPanel >
         <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName}">
         <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="thePageBlock" status="status" />
         </apex:inputField>
         <apex:actionStatus startText="applying value..." id="status"/>
         </apex:outputPanel>
      </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
   <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Amount}"/>
   <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.CloseDate}"/>
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
   </apex:actionRegion>
   <apex:pageBlockSection title="Closed Lost Information" columns="1" rendered="{!opportunity.stageName == 'Closed Lost'}">
      <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.CloseDate}" required="true"/>
   </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Anil, welcome to Salesforce StackExchange. I've edited your post to make your code visible. When posting code, either paste it in as pre-formatted text or use the spacebar to indent each line at least 4 spaces. Otherwise, any code you post won't be visible to readers. You'll see your reply below when composing your post. You can also use an accent (below the tilde key) to surround code so that it appears correctly when posting it in-line with a reply. Not to worry, I had the same problem when I first came here too! :)